# Monotouch auto resizing views in iphone

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I have created a view in interface builder that contains another view (content area) and a button bar at the bottom.

The hierarchy is as:

```
->View
--->mapContainer UIView
----->map MKMapView
----->OverlayView UIView
--->ToolBar UIToolBar
```

I would like the mapContainer to resize to full window when the ToolBar is hidden.
I would like the map and the OverlayView to resize to the mapContainer size

I have attempted the following code, but it has no effect.  Please advise?

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
  base.ViewDidLoad ();
  this.mapContainer.AutosizesSubviews = true ;
  this.View.AutosizesSubviews = true ;
  try
  {
    this.mapContainer.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth ;
    this.map.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth ;
    this.map.SizeToFit();
    this.mapContainer.SizeToFit();
    this.map.SizeToFit();
    this.View.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0,0,this.View.Frame.Width, this.View.Frame.Height );
    this.mapContainer.LayoutSubviews();

  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    Console.Write(ex.ToString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to redraw the subviews in an overridden method public override void LayoutSubviews with your class.

There you can reset the frames of all your frames. The method SizeToFit() has a tendency to not work as it's name sounds... So first size to fit, then reset the frame.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article may be this can help you.Its not related to monotouch but it will give nice concept of how to arrange elements together in IB.
http://programmingobsession.blogspot.com/2009/05/real-world-iphone-rotation-part-1.html